# wire:ignore makes the attribute null in livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm using a choices-tags select list in my livewire project and the options are **permissionCategories** which I made a property like this

```
public function getPermissionCatsProperty(){
        return PermissionCategory::get();
    }
```

and this **permissionCategory** has it's children of permissions
and when I edit a role I want to make the permissions of this role selected in the select list

This is my select list i made in a component named **choices-select**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <label class="mt-4 form-label">Tags</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="{{$name}}" id="choices-tags" multiple>
            {{$slot}}
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

@push('js')
    <script src="../../../assets/js/plugins/choices.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        if (document.getElementById('choices-tags')) {
            var tags = document.getElementById('choices-tags');
            const examples = new Choices(tags, {
                removeItemButton: true
            });
        }
    </script>
@endpush
```

and i'm using it in the form modal like this

```
                     <div wire:ignore>
                        <x-choices-select :name="'permissions[]'">
                            <option value="">Select Permission</option>
                            @if(isset($this->permissionCats))
                                @foreach($this->permissionCats as $category)
                                    <optgroup label="{{$category->name}}">
                                        @if(isset($category->permissions))
                                            @foreach($category->permissions as $permission)
                                                <option value="{{$permission->id}}" {{@$role->hasPermissionTo($permission->name) ? :'selected' : ''}}>{{@$permission->name}}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        @endif
                                    </optgroup>
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                        </x-choices-select>
                    </div>
```

and the **$role** variable is coming from here

```
public $role;
    public function edit($role_id)
    {

        $this->resetValidation();
        $this->role = Role::firstWhere('id', $role_id);

        $this->modalType = 'edit';
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('show-modal', ['modal_id' => 'create_role']);

    }
```

The **permissionCats** is working fine but the problem is in **$role** variable and I'm sure that the **$role** variable is working fine every where in the form because when I edit some role the fields in the form modal takes the values of the **$role** i'm trying to edit.
But the problem is when i use **wire:ignore** for the select list the **$role** variable becomes null inside of the select list, but if i don't use **wire:ignore** to the select list this time the $role variable works fine but the classes and the js of the select list gets away.
I tried everything i can to solve it but i couldn't, i even tried to put the select list in a livewire component for it self and use it inside the first one and whenever i try to edit a role i do **emit** to it with the **$role** variable but it was still not working and coming null to the select list.

If you know how to solve it help me please and thank you all.